# react-native webview image Click to enlarge

Tags: react-native, webview, image-enlarge

My page is webview display html code returned by the background program.
Now need to achieve click image to enlarge effect,And if there is more than one picture in the page, a picture list appears, can swipe right and left.I do not have a solution to the problem now.
If you know how to solve please tell me the idea, or will need to use the component to tell me.
If you have a sample program, that would be better.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Webview has very limited controls and what happens inside the webview is mostly dependent on the website that is being displayed.

Why not Instead of showing a webview, you do a get request to the webview url, get the whole page's html as response, filter out the images from it and then display it in a component itself without webview?

Comment: No webview?Get the contents of the entire page, all converted to react-native component?

Comment: No, that's a huge task. Instead get the entire page, filter out the images and stuff that you need, put it in a component and display it to the user.